# How do I find out if there will be a fsck during the next boot?

Tags: fsck

Is there a way to find out if a filesystem check is scheduled for the next boot?

Maybe it's similar to a forced check, which gets triggered by the existence of the file `/forcefsck`?

Comment: Besides command-line tools like dumpe2fs and tune2fs, are there any GUI tools for finding this out?  It would seem like a good feature for Gnome Disk Utility (palimpsest) but I don't see it there, or in Gparted....

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It depends on your filesystem, in addition to /forcefsck .

With ext2, ext3 and ext4 you can use

```
dumpe2fs -h /dev/diskname
```

Where diskname is for example sda1. You can determine name of your disk partition by running command

```
mount
```

Example output (only partly):

```
/dev/xvda1 on / type ext3 (rw,noatime,usrquota,errors=remount-ro)
```

Where xvda1 is name of root disk partition.

For dumpe2fs three interesting items are

```
Mount count:              9
Maximum mount count:      36
Next check after:         Mon Feb 14 09:31:33 2011
```

Ubuntu will run fsck if mount count is equal or greater than maximum mount count, or if "next check after" is passed.

Answer (score 10):

Starting in Ubuntu 11.04, this information will be shown in your `/etc/motd` file, using the tool [/usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-fsck-at-reboot](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/natty/update-notifier/natty/view/head:/data/update-motd-fsck-at-reboot), which checks ext2/3/4 partitions for both date-based and count-based auto-fsck events. You can run it manually like this:

```
sudo /usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-fsck-at-reboot --force
```

and it will report any partitions that will be checked on the next reboot.

Comment: Also, `cat /var/lib/update-notifier/fsck-at-reboot` to see the status from the last run without requiring elevated privileges.

Answer (score 5):

There's a utility called [showfsck](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/showfsck) that will tell you how many mounts are left until the next scheduled `fsck`.

Comment: showfsck do not show timed fsck's: ext2/ext3/ext4 is checked on every nth mount or after x days since last fsck, whichever comes first.

Comment: @Olli: good point - I'm primarily a laptop user so I boot very often and forgot about the timed fsck's

Answer (score 0):

If you have an ext4 partition you can see how many times it has been mounted:

```
sudo dumpe2fs -h /dev/sda1 | grep Mount
```