# Polarr Photo Editor will not install 18.04

Tags: 18.04, snap, photo, image-editor

I have tried to install the Polarr photo editor 1/2 dz times either from the software or snap all have failed. Software center looks like it has installed but will not launch. Using snap it fails to even install with this error message:

```
sudo snap install polarr
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Fetch and check assertions for snap "polarr" (9) (Get https://api.snapcraft.io/api/v1/snaps/assertions/snap-revision/7Gj-KkZig4Fq41jE0onllCWjATUViyNVmRySSFi1xpQlTiLQZQgK_iQleURBAOTY?max-format=0: net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers))
```

The link is no help. I tried emailing support and get this;//support@polarr.co (after RCPT TO): 550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

You may be affected by [this bug.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/snappy/+bug/1639981) There are a couple workarounds listed in the comments to the bug that may or may not help in your specific situation. As an alternative you might be more successful installing Polarr Photo Editor via [this page](https://snapcraft.io/polarr) and the Desktop Store. The latter approach worked for me.

Comment: apt-get would not install tcpdump, too many errors, tried snap first but it couldn't find tcpdump.

Comment: apt-get would not install tcpdump, too many errors, tried snap first but it couldn't find tcpdump. I saved the errors don't remember how to put them in a link to post. I did try 'this page' with no luck and no error as to why. I did find the 'Debugging Procedures' page haven't had a chance to work my through it yet. I do have some issues with ubuntu video and mouse I need to work out.

Comment: @LGGriffin Welcome to AskUbuntu! Your question here was regarding Polarr photo editor. It seems you have other questions as well. Please [edit] your post to clarify exactly what your problem is. Thank you for helping us help you! You should also review https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask Cheers!

Comment: The tcpdump problems originate from trying to pursue your comment to "You may be affected by this bug". Since I can't install tcpdump I 'm then no closer to determining the problem. Yes there are multiple problems perhaps the "DebuggingProcedures" may have answers.

Comment: @LGGriffin In that case you can obtain `tcpdump` for 18.04 [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/tcpdump)

Comment: Well another failure to install. What has been an intermittent annoyance has now become a real problem. I did a 'dpkg --verify'' ,more errors than I want to think about, I'm not sure how valid they maybe. I'm going to check the integrity of the HD and then make debugging my priority for the weekend.

Comment: @LGGriffin You might start with a quick check of [RAM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/591488/how-do-i-run-memtest86) and [SMART data](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528072/how-can-i-check-the-smart-status-of-a-ssd-or-hdd-on-current-versions-of-ubuntu-1/528077#528077) and also [check the filesystem.](https://askubuntu.com/a/953293/225694) It's hard to determine what's going on without the errors (like your output from dpkg --verify)

Comment: Good ideas all things I did once upon a time as a PC tech. I either run the memtest tonight or Spinrite right now leaning towards Spintrite because there have been errors creating directories, but I also have to find the CD. SMART is not a choice because the gui can't find gtk that's another error found in the boot and bootstrap logs. It maybe that I will have to look for my spinrite CD and thumb drive to boot live 18.04 from and try and repair.

Comment: The solution was something of an anticlimax. I fooled around with liveusb trying to find a way to fix the file system and did multiple searches no luck. Finally a search had the 'disks'. '