# Ubuntu doesn't boot after install, huge swapfile

Tags: 18.04

Was working without issue within Ubuntu 18.04 on a dual-boot machine.

Installed a tex ide via the command line:

```
sudo apt-get install texmaker
```

which appeared to complete successfully.  I subsequently clicked on the first gummi link in a response on [this SE page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235043/what-latex-editor-do-you-suggest-for-linux), which lanched a new tab, appeared to be resolving, but never fully resolved after a minute or so.  I closed it, launched a new tab and searched, never successfully getting to the page.

I wasn't doing much otherwise, just watching a youtube vid on an adjacent screen and realized my memory was blocked up after getting errors to `cd` via the command line.  I tried a `df` on my home directory to see what might be causing it and showed most dirs with normal memory allocations, but a huge swapfile, multiple gigs.  I tried restarting to clear it, but haven't been able to get back in.

I'd allocated 40GB for the Ubuntu partition, and don't save anything substantial there barring a couple GB movie files in the last couple days, without issue, so I wouldn't expect the recent install of texmaker would have changed things, even at 1GB+.  Checking Windows disk manager shows 100% free, not sure whether that's good or bad (partition 5):

[image]

Any thoughts on how to diagnose and fix.

**Edit (with additional boot detail)**:
I'm able to boot, select Ubuntu from within the grub dialogue, and ultimately end up on a command-line looking screen with a version of:

```
/dev/p5 clean 234234/2342234 files, 234234/2324234 blocks
```

after which it hangs.

**Edit 2**:
I was able to boot into recovery mode and get to a terminal.  `fsck`, `dpkg`, and `clean` all fail to resolve the issue.  `fsck` aborts with '/dev/p5 is mounted, aborting' message.

I've included a picture of the error `fsck` returns as well as one of `ll` showing memory use (and the offending swapfile).
[image]
[image]

Comment: Windows cannot read the contents of Linux partitions, so your result from Windows does not show anything bad. Can’t you boot Ubuntu at all? Please [edit] your question to add the information what happens if you try to boot Ubuntu.

Comment: @Melebius, updated.

Comment: Thanks. Can you switch to a [virtual console](https://superuser.com/a/458507/84807)?

Comment: I'm not able to get to anything graphical to switch to VT.  could probably boot into recovery mode to get access to the command line to run diagnostics if that's what you're thinking

Comment: you could start your pc with a live usb stick too... then rework the swapfile, run fsck and other diag/repair tools

Comment: @cmak.fr, updated with fsck detail.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use fsck in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/353732/how-to-use-fsck-in-ubuntu)

Comment: @Chris: as i wrote, to run fsck you'd better boot from LiveUSB stick... Since you are running the recovery console, you should rework your swapfile (See https://askubuntu.com/a/1049496/77093)