# Ubuntu not starting up

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04

I was starting Ubuntu and got this error:

```
EXT4 -fs sda9 Found ext4 file system with invalid superblock checksum
Run e2fsck
Your are in emergency mode
```

Comment: I'd suggest you boot *live* media (such as Ubuntu install media and use in the *Try Ubuntu* mode) and `fsck` your system. If it detects issues and fixes them (which I'd expect to occur), you'll likely find it boots normally next time you try.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use fsck in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/353732/how-to-use-fsck-in-ubuntu)