# Ubuntu doesn't boot after forced shutdown

Tags: kubuntu

I have problem with my Kubuntu, I forced it to shutdown by turn on button, and it doesn't want to boot, stops at laptop logo. In recovery mode I used `sudo -fsck -f / cmd` and I see this `/dev/sda5` is mounted, cannot continue, aborting.

Comment: After a forced shutdown bad things can happen. The fastest fix is a re install.

Comment: Will probably need to fix with an USB with partitions unmounted.  Very bad things can happen if try to fix mounted partition.  Should copy/backup data before fixing if possible.

Comment: You must either boot from a LiveUSB or use [forcefsck-and-reboot](https://askubuntu.com/a/353733/19626) in order to fsck your system partition. The system partition must be mounted for Recovery Mode.