# How to fix ubuntu not starting error fsck fill systrm

Tags: boot, 20.04, grub2, filesystem, fsck

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0LYN.jpg)

Help this problam see my image

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use fsck in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/353732/how-to-use-fsck-in-ubuntu)

Comment: All you should have to do is to type in `fsck /dev/sda3` and fix any problems it detects.  After it is done, try rebooting your system.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fsck error on boot: /dev/sda6: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY](https://askubuntu.com/questions/697190/fsck-error-on-boot-dev-sda6-unexpected-inconsistency-run-fsck-manually)